# Express REST API login going straight to 401 error

Tags: javascript, express

I have this controller for a login route, the only problem is that it doesn't work... It worked yesterday, I haven't changed anything and now it doesn't. It just falls through to the catch block and errors out, however it doesn't actually have an error, and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

**Here is my app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const systemRoutes = require('./routes/system');
const recipeRoutes = require('./routes/recipes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Change later to only allow our server
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});


app.use('/api/system', systemRoutes);
app.use('/api/feed', recipeRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);


// TODO: Add error handling and validation


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/learn')
    .then(result => {
        app.listen(8080);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
    let fetchedUser;
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth failed'
                });
            }

            fetchedUser = user;
            return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
        })
        .then(result => {
            if (!result) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth failed'
                });
            }

            // TODO: Replace "secret_sauce" with secret key
            const token = jwt.sign(
                { username: fetchedUser.username, userId: fetchedUser._id },
                'secret_sauce',
                { expiresIn: '30d' }
            );

            res.status(200).json({
                token: token,
                userId: fetchedUser._id
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Error trying to login',
                error: err
            });
        });
}
```

Also, here's a picture of the error:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and finding out where the error occurs?

Comment: @incorelabs Yeah, I couldn't find anything, just that it falls through to the catch block

Comment: The https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6wyS.png image shows that the server’s responding with a 401 error, and that the error message from the server is *“Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login: 401 Unauthorized”*. So it seems like what you need to figure out is what’s causing the server to consider the request to be unauthorized. You probably want to check the server logs to see what additional details the server is logging on the server side before it responds with that 401.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is very little information about what's wrong I'm just going to try to suggest some other approach to debugging:

Have you checked what comes in the `req.body`?

And, are you sure it's falling through to the `catch` statement? Because if it did, the error object shouldn't be empty.

My advice, in order to discard that possibility would be to change the error messages you are throwing to something more representative of the block they are being thrown of. For example, `cannot find that userId` for the first time you send `res.status(401)`.

Another advice is to actually change the status codes to better transmite the kind of error happening. A forbidden mostly relates to client side errors - trying to access a protected route without a valid token for example.

For example:

```
  if(!user) {
    res.status(404).json({
      message: 'Couldn\'t find the username provided.'
     });
    }
```

I hope it was helpful feedback!